# Prove that this functional is a continuous linear functional and find its norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that this functional is continuous linear functional in $C[-1,1]$ and find its norm.

$\int_0^1 tx(t)dt-x(1)$

What I have so far:

1) I think I proved the linearity by changing $x$ to $(x+y)$ and getting $F(x)+F(y)$ as a result and changing $x$ to $(dx)$ which leads to $d*F(x)$. Is it correct though?

And I don't know what to do further with continuity and norm.
I translated it from another language so I could make a term mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity follows from linearity of the integral and evaluation $ x \mapsto x(1)$.

It should be clear that 
$|f(x)| \le \int_0^1 t \|x\| dt + \|x\| = {3 \over 2} \|x\|$.

If we could set $x(t) = 1$ for $t \in [0,1)$ and $x(1) = -1$ then it is clear that $|f(x)|={3 \over 2}\|x\|$, but we need $x$ to be continuous.

So, we see if an approximation works and let $x_n(t) = 1$ for $x \in [-1,1-{1 \over n}]$ and $x_n(t) = 1-2n(t-(1-{1 \over n}))$ otherwise and a little bit of work shows that
$\lim_n |f(x_n)| = {3 \over 2}$ (and, of course, $\|x_n\| = 1$). Hence $\|f\| = {3 \over 2}$.

Comment: +1. They say great minds think alike -:). I got an identical answer but I was much slower than you.

Comment: I'm sorry why is that clear? I've just started digging into it and nothing is clear to me at the moment :\

Comment: It follows from $|a+b| \le |a+b|$ and $|\int f| \le \int |f|$.

Comment: Your solution is great, I'm still too ignoramus though and can't really understand the flow completely. Can you elaborate a little bit the last part? How and what for would we choose xn(t)=1 and xn(t)=1−2n(t−(1−1/n))? I found the similar way of solving but I can't understand where these equasions come from

Comment: Understand the 2nd last paragraph first, that's the basic idea. Sketch the functions $x_n$ to see what I am doing, basically using continuous functions to approximate a discontinuous one.

Comment: So n is just a very very small number, as little as it can be right? Also should  x∈[−1,1−1/n] or x∈[0,1−1/n]? And I still can't understand where xn(t)=1−2n(t−(1−1/n)) comes from. Did you calculate it somehow, or is it constant or too obvious?

Comment: No, $n$ is large, so the slope of the non constant part is very steep.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I actually meant 1/n is small so 1 - 1/n gets very close to 1.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry again, 2 hours passed and I still didn't understand how you get xn(t)=1−2n(t−(1−1/n)). The rest is clearish now

Comment: Have you sketched the function?

Comment: I tried to, not sure if anything I did is correct. I sketched x(t)=1, x(t)=1, x(1)=-1. Am I on the right path?